# Andengine: Connect two bodies

Tags: android, andengine, physics, game-physics

I'm creating a simple game, I've tried to create a small piece that when it's collides
with another body it's sticks to this another body.

Here a snippet:

```
ContactListner(){
    ...

    Body b1 = x1.getBody();
    Body b2 = x2.getBody();
    Player p = ((Player) x2.getBody().getUserData());
    DistanceJointDef d = new DistanceJointDef();
    d.initialize(b1, b2, b1.getWorldCenter(), b2.getWorldCenter());
    d.collideConnected=true;
    physicsWorld.createJoint(d);
```

My ContactListner is working, but this body isn't connecting both bodies.
Both of then are Dynamic Bodies.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify the world in Step()-Call of Box2D because the World is locked!. See [Box2D AndEngine: app hangs out when creating Joints during ContactListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912254/box2d-andengine-app-hangs-out-when-creating-joints-during-contactlistener)